# How to delete string from given data in python(without using any built-in function)?

Tags: python, string

I have created `Insertstring` function in this way:

```
def Insertstring(data,text,pos):
    count = 0
    Str = ""
    for i in data:
        if count==pos:
            Str+=text
        count+=1
        Str+=i      
    return Str

print(InsertStr("abcde","f",0))
```

It's working in the right way.

**Output:**

```
fabcde
```

I want to create `Deletestring` function in the same way. (It should return the remaining string)

```
#pos = Starting index to delete
#length = Length of data to be deleted

def Deletestring(data,pos,length):
    pass

print(InsertStr("abcde",2,3))
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ab
```

Comment: You need to pass them to right function.

Comment: Your insert function can also be written: `def insert_string(existing, new, position):` `return existing[:position] + new + existing[position:] if 0 <= position <= len(existing) else existing` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any built-ins, you can do just slicing:

```
def delete_string(data, pos, length):
    return data[:pos] + data[pos+length:]

print(delete_string("abcde", 2, 3))
# ab
```

Answer (score 0):

String slicing can be done to remove the character(s) from the string - We can remove characters from string by slicing the string into pieces and then joining back those pieces.

We can slice a string using operator [].

```
stringObject[ start : stop : interval]
```

It returns a new string object containing parts of given string i.e. it selects a range from `start` to `stop-1` with given step size i.e. `interval`. You can find the details regarding this [here](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-remove-characters-from-a-string-by-index/).

```
def Deletestring(data,pos,length):
    return data[:pos] + data[pos+length:]

strObj = "This is a sample string"
pos = 6
length = 5

print("Original String => %s" % (strObj))
print("After Delete at pos %d and length %d => %s" % (pos, length, Deletestring(strObj, pos, length)))
```

Output:

```
Original String => This is a sample string
After Delete at pos 6 and length 5 => This iample string
```

Comment: You don't need an `if` check, because slicing handles that edge case itself. Not to mention that then it would boil down to an answer posted much before.